# tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() error: logits and labels must be same size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and am trying to write an algorithm to classify images in the CIFAR-10 dataset. I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[10000,10] labels_size=[1,10000]
     [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape, Reshape_1)]]
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import cPickle

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100
image_size = 32*32*3 # because 3 channels

x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(None, image_size)) 
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([image_size, n_nodes_hl1])), 'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])), 'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])), 'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(I am new to TensorFlow and tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])), 'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    # input_data * weights + biases
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    # activation function
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']
    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))//THIS IS LINE 48 WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    #learning rate = 0.001
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in range(5):
                with open('data_batch_'+str(i+1),'rb') as f:
                    train_data = cPickle.load(f)
                print train_data
                print prediction.get_shape()
                #print len(y)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x:train_data['data'],y:train_data['labels']})
                epoch_loss += c
            print 'Epoch ' + str(epoch) + ' completed out of ' + str(hm_epochs) + ' loss: ' + str(epoch_loss)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        with open('test_batch','rb') as f:
            test_data = cPickle.load(f)
            accuracy = accuracy.eval({x:test_data['data'],y:test_data['labels']})
        print 'Accuracy: ' + str(accuracy)

train_neural_network(x)
```

I'm pretty sure this means that in line 48 (shown above) `prediction` and `y` are not the same shape, but I don't understand TensorFlow well enough to know how to fix it. I don't even really understand where `y` is being set, I got most of this code from a tutorial and fiddled with it to apply it to a different dataset. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) op expects its `logits` and `labels` arguments to be tensors with the same shape. Furthermore, the `logits` and `labels` arguments should be 2-D tensors (matrices) with `batch_size` rows, and `num_classes` columns.

From the error message and the size of `logits`, I'm guessing that `batch_size` is 10000, and `num_classes` is 10. From the size of `labels`, I'm guessing that your labels are encoded as a list of integers, where the integer represent the index of the class for the corresponding input example. (I'd have expected this to be a `tf.int32` value, rather than `tf.float32` as it appears to be in your program, but perhaps there is some automatic conversion going on.)

In TensorFlow, you can use the [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) to compute cross-entropy on data in this form. In your program, you could do this by replacing the `cost` calculation with:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    prediction, tf.squeeze(y)))
```

Note that the [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#squeeze) op is needed to convert `y` into a vector of length `batch_size` (in order to be a valid argument to `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`.

Comment: I added `tf.squeeze()` and am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you also switch to `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`?

Comment: Didn't see that, thank you. Now I get `TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64` I think this is related to what you were talking about. Can I just change `y = tf.placeholder('float')` to `y = tf.placeholder('int')`?

Comment: Almost: defining `y` as `y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)` should work. Now the remaining question is what the type of `train_data['labels']` is, because its type will be checked when you do `sess.run([optimizer, cost], ...)`. (It's being read from a pickle file, so I can't tell what it is. You may need to convert it to an array (or list) of integers.)

Comment: `y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)` worked. Now I get this error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Minimum tensor rank: 2 but got: 1` at this line `correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some updates to the code to support TensorFlow version 1.0:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    #OLD VERSION:
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    #NEW:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #OLD: 
        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        #NEW:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```